# apps script, To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

I am trying to write a code that transfers data from gmail to spreadsheet. Here is the code:

```
function mailToStudio() {
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('GmailToStudio');
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  for (var i = threads.length - 1; i>=0; i--){
    var msg = threads[i].getMessages()[0];
    extractDetails(msg);
    GmailApp.markMessageRead(msg);
  }
}

function extractDetails(msg) {
  var dateTime = msg.getDate();
  var subjectText = msg.getSubject();
  var senderDetails = msg.getFrom();
  var body = msg.getPlainBody();
  Logger.log(body);
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  activeSheet.appendRow([dateTime, subjectText, senderDetails, body]);
}
```

My issue is with gmail body part. I want the data starting "Client Time" text and ending "Total" to be copied to spreadsheet in rows and columns same as given in gmail body.

Here is what I get:
1- When there are only few data lines in gmail body then the code works in such a way that it puts whole body content in a single cell instead of copying it to different rows and columns according to data structure.

2- When there are more data lines like 50+ lines in gmail body then the code does not work and all I get from body is an error "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!".

Can anybody help how I can move gmail data to spreadsheet in proper rows and columns?

Thank you

Comment: I have tried your code without any changes (just the label name) and it has worked with no errors. I have created a Spreadsheet and then opened the script editor bounded to that sheet. Copied your code and changed label name and it worked. Do you have it like that?

Comment: It works fine if I have only few rows of data in gmail body. However it gives above error if I have more rows like 100 rows of data. How can I get that data in a spreadsheet in rows and columns?

Comment: Can you share examples of the email. Screenshot'll do.

Comment: Here is an example email. All emails have same format
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y_yh8R4jiwM3QNMU3WyUaejSW3RG09WT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It still didn't show me the error. How many emails are you getting? Have you checked at the quota limits? See: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota#per-method_quota_usage